# Convert or Cast vchar to int without character '-' or -

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, casting

I need select in SQL Table this (00-00066) and get after convert this (0000066)

just like>>>>>

```
declare @v1 varchar(21) = '00-00066', --- I need ignore this character '-'
    @v2 varchar(21) = '000    -     66   ',
    @v3 varchar(21) = '00-66' + char(13) + char(10),
    @v4 varchar(21) = char(9) + '66000-00'
```

select cast(@v1 as int)   -- error
select cast(@v2 as int)   -- error
select cast(@v3 as int)   -- error
select cast(@v4 as int)   -- error

Comment: if convert to int the zeros at the front will disappear, why not just use replace like _ select replace(@v1,'-','')

Answer (score 1):

[DigitsOnlyEE](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/String+Function/141686/) was developed specifically for this problem and is does it faster than any function I've seen. You just have to grab the code to create it from the link provided.

Here's a quick example of how it works:

```
SELECT DigitsOnly FROM dbo.DigitsOnlyEE('000    -     66   ');
```

Results:

```
00066
```

To use against a table:

```
-- sample data
DECLARE @table TABLE (oldString varchar(100));
INSERT @table VALUES ('00-00066'),('000    -     66   '),
('00-66' + char(13) + char(10)), (char(9) + '66000-00');

-- solution
SELECT oldString, DigitsOnly
FROM @table
CROSS APPLY dbo.DigitsOnlyEE(oldString);
```

Results:

[image]